# Passing a file as a paramater to another class in Java throws the error "File or Directory not found"

Tags: java, file, class, parameters, package

I'm trying to pass a file from the main method to another class that should handle it, but while the file is recognized in the main class, it throws this error in the second one.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/giovanni/Desktop/spring-course/exercises-part2/word-inspection/target/classes/words.txt (File o directory non esistente)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:639)
    at com.vanny96.WordInspection.<init>(WordInspection.java:16)
    at com.vanny96.App.main(App.java:13)
```

The path for the file is correct, and the file is there, so I have no idea why it isn't working.

I tried looking around for a solution but couldn't find any, and the fact that the file works fine in the main method while not in another one confused me a lot, if you could point me to a thread where this is solved it would be enough!

Here is the code:

Main App

```
package com.vanny96;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.URL;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        URL fileUrl = App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("words.txt");
        File file = new File(fileUrl.toString());

        WordInspection inspector = new WordInspection(file);        
    }
}
```

WordInspection class

```
package com.vanny96;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordInspection {
  private File file;
  private Scanner reader;

  public WordInspection(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {

    this.file = file;
    this.reader = new Scanner(this.file);
  }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with passing the `File` as a parameter whatsoever. It has to do with the non-existence of the underlying file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Scanner is not able to resolve the file as an URL, but is able to resolve it as an URI.

If you change the line:

`File file = new File(fileUrl.toString());`

to

`File file = new File(fileUrl.toURI());`

your Scanner should be able to resolve the file (i have tested it). You will have to add an additional throws class for the `toUri()` method.

Comment: It works!! Thank you very much! I do think it is strange tough, but java has plenty of strange things so I should stop questioning it and just re-learn things in the java-way

Comment: Glad i could help :)